# Ember 1.12 Cannot read property 'moduleName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I updated my Ember version from 1.11 to 1.12 and now I'm getting this error message on console when trying to run the app:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleName' of undefined

Any idea why? And how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to update Ember Template Compiler.

Don't forget to update all Ember parts.

[Link to most recent Ember releases](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release)